# Where is "sf-contener clearfix" end tag? Prestashop 1.5.3.1

Tags: prestashop

I'm working on a project for Prestashop and I have the following file:

**blocktopmenu.tpl**

**https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/master/modules/blocktopmenu/blocktopmenu.tpl**

I need to know where is the end tag for "sf-contener clearfix" **< / div >**

Any idea?

Thks and sorry my english!

------ EDITED POST ------

i tried it, but no work for me :(((

I placed "exampleDiv" right here:

**header.tpl**

```
<div id="header_right" class="grid_6 omega">
     {$HOOK_TOP}
     <div id="exampleDiv"></div>
</div>
```

but i look this result in Firebug:

```
<div id="header" class="grid_9 alpha omega">
   <a id="header_logo" href="#"></a>
   <div id="header_right" class="grid_6 omega">
   <div id="topMenu_bg_up"></div>
   <div class="sf-contener clearfix"></div>
   **i wanna to play here :D**
</div>

<div id="minic_slider" class="theme-default"></div>

<div style="display:none;">
   <div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      <div id="exampleDiv"></div>
      **but it work in this other place :(**
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to add stuff after the blocktopmenu module?

Comment: yes, just after end tag </div>

Answer (score 0):

Here :
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/master/themes/default/header.tpl#L84

The  #header_right is closed in blocktopmenu.tpl and the topmenu is displayed under.

Edit : If you want to add content just after the topmenu, the best way is to create e module, hook it on toppage and position it just after the blocktopmenu.

Comment: I think it's better to do it inside <div> tags.

I tried it:
<div id="new_topmenu_up"></div>
<div id="topmenu"></div>
<div id="new_topmenu_down"></div>

but it is very difficult or confused for me. In this case i will do the following:

<div id="topmenu">
     <div id="new_topmenu_up"></div>
     <!-- UL menu -->
     <div id="new_topmenu_down"></div>
</div>

I think that this is the best solution for me now. Thnks all for to help me :)